# What is the proper way to access datastore in custom Model Binders?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, modelbinders

How should I properly implement data access in my custom model binders?

Like in controllers I use IContentRepository and then have it create an instance of its implementing class in constructor. So I have everything ready for incorporating IoC (DI) at a later stage.

Now I need something similar in model binder. I need to make some DB lookups in the binder. I'm thinking of doing it the same way I do it in controllers but I am open to suggestion.

This is a snippet from one of my controllers so you can imagine how I'm doing it in them:

```
        public class WidgetZoneController : BaseController
        {
// BaseController has IContentRepository ContentRepository field
            public WidgetZoneController() : this(new XmlWidgetZoneRepository())
            {
            }

            public WidgetZoneController(IContentRepository repository)
            {
                ContentRepository = repository;
            }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the binder typically bind an entity, you don't need a specific repository like `IContentRepository`, indeed `IRepository<T>` will be good to get the entity.

To instantiate the IRipository you can use something like that:

> ```
> var repositoryType = typeof (IRepository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
> ```

I suggest you take a look on the CodeCampServer implementation of entities binder, over here:

http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/source/browse/trunk#trunk/src/UI/Binders/Entities

Answer (score 0):

You can use constructor injection to your custom model binder class, and also inherit from the DefaultModelBinder.

```
public class MyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    IContentRepository ContentRepository;

    public MyModelBinder(IContentRepository contentRepository)
    {
        this.ContentRepository = contentRepository;
    }
```

With custom model binders, you register them in Application_Start() like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.Binders.Add(
           typeof(MyModel), new MyModelBinder(contentRepository)
    );
```

Now when using IoC, you need to keep in mind the lifetime of your objects. When you use IoC with Controllers, they exist per web request. So if you inject the Repository, any data connections or OR/M sessions will exist for only that short time.

With the Model Binder, it is basically a long-lived Singleton ( Application_Start() ). So make sure your Repository works in both cases.